# How to convert audio file to picture for every 0.1 seconds in python

Tags: python-3.x, image, voice

I have an auido file of the engine. I would like to convert it into the spectrogram.
    
    `import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
    from scipy import signal
    from scipy.io import wavfile
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    samplingFrequency, signalData = wavfile.read('datamusic/car2.wav')
    plot.subplot(111)
    plot.specgram(signalData,Fs=samplingFrequency)
    plot.savefig("datapicture/car2.png")`

It is the code that o have found. However it converts all sound.

Comment: You should include a more complete code sample with imports.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have edited